# How to use disableControls for all controls in a form except for the field which belongs to a tdblookup

Tags: delphi

I designed a form using delphi IDE.  All controls belong to dataset1. I have also a dbcombo
with dataset1 as lookup.

When I disableControls and drop down the combo I have a limited list so I can not scrolldown the combo list. Is it possible to solve that ?

Med

Comment: Simple:  Use a separate instance of the dataset to populate the TDBLookUpCombo.

Comment: Generally with that sort of user interface I'd have all the data-aware controls in a TGroupBox except for the TDBLookupCombo. You then just enable/disable the groupbox and don't call TDataSet.DisableControls at all.

Comment: TDataSet DisableControls/EnableControls is typically used when you are going to temporarily change the dataset cursor position and you don't want your bound controls flickering while that happens. I rarely use it as a general control disabling mechanism like you're doing here.

Comment: TDataSet DisableControls/EnableControls is the only general method I believe.  activate/desactivate controls is not an universal way to do. it's specific to each form.

Comment: First comment is most valid in my opinion.  Do not forget to set recno after close dropdown and close the dataset2 after open  beforedropdown .